# Blazor component dynamic authorization

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to get Blazor authentication to work dynamically for a Razor page/ component.
I'll illustrate with an example of what I'm trying to achieve...

Let's say you have 2 users with 2 different roles:
User 1 has `user` role
User 2 has `user` and `admin` roles

They're trying to access the same component (`/queue/{queueType:string}`) through `/queue/user` and `/queue/admin`.
In our example, user 1 will be able to access only the `/queue/user` and not `/queue/admin` component, but user 2 will be able to access both.

```
@page "/queue/{queueType:string}"
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = queueType)] <-- an object reference is required for queueType
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it that way, you can try the following:

```
@page "/queue/user"
@page "/queue/admin"
```

Then when you define the UI elements, you can wrap them in `<AuthorizeView Roles="admin">` and show different things for the user and admin roles.

Comment: I didn't know I could use @page multiple times. But this doesn't really fit my scenario as most of the code is reusable. The `queueType` is just used for the API route that fetches the different items. I think I managed to get it working with an ```if (queueType == "admin") @attribute [Authorize(Roles = Admin)]```, but I'm gonna try for something more tidy